# Appium timeout error while running automation on cloud devices

Tags: appium, adb, appium-android

I am using appium for automate android application on cloud device but getting timeout error when try to launch activity on device

Below are the capabilitites which I set

```
public void AppiumConfigurationCommonMethod(String appPackage,String activity) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {    
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", devicename);
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", activity);
        caps.setCapability("noReset","true");
        caps.setCapability("adbExecTimeout",200000);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,20000);
        System.out.println("about to launch");
        try {
           Initialization.driverAppium=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        sleep(5);
    }
```

On checking appium server the logs mentioned are as follows :

Running 'D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s astrofarm.42gears.com:10096 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy' Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1618973276050 (08:17:56 GmT+0530 (India Standard Time)) Encountered internal error running command: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s astrofarm.42gears.com:10096 push C:\Users\DRASHT-1.MAN\AppData\Local\Temp\2021321-796-12uutpa.6wze\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/Occ1725a60a05dbb5d0d09256f2fc6ece7e3b10f.apk' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability Error: Command 'D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s astrofarm.42gears.com:10096 push C:\Users\DRASHT-1.MAN\AppData\Local\Temp\2021321-796-12uutpa.6wze\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/Occ1725a60a05dbb5d0d09256f2fc6ece7e3b10f.apk' timed out after 20000ms • at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\teen_process\lib\exec.js: • at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11) • at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5) • at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5) • at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10) <-- POST
/wd/hub/session 500

Comment: Please help me on this issue as soon as possible